# Convert node tree to dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the node class definition with tree structure (built using node instance) of programming languages. Now how to convert hierarchical node data tree structure to python dictionary using node class method ?
See desired output at bottom.

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self._name = name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent

        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)

    def addChild(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent


rootNode   = nodeData.Node("books")
web_node = nodeData.Node("web", rootNode)
database_node = nodeData.Node("database", rootNode)
front_end_node = nodeData.Node("front-end", web_node)
back_end_node = nodeData.Node("back-end", web_node)
sql_node = nodeData.Node("sql", database_node)
nosql_node = nodeData.Node("nosql", database_node)
html_node = nodeData.Node("html", front_end_node)
css_node = nodeData.Node("css", front_end_node)
js_node = nodeData.Node("js", front_end_node)
php_node = nodeData.Node("php", back_end_node)
python_node = nodeData.Node("python", back_end_node)
mysql_node = nodeData.Node("mysql", sql_node)
postgresql_node = nodeData.Node("postgresql", sql_node)
mongodb_node = nodeData.Node("mongodb", nosql_node)
cassandra_node = nodeData.Node("cassandra", nosql_node)
html_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("the missing manual", html_node)
html_book_two_node = nodeData.Node("core html5 canvas", html_node)
css_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("css pocket reference", css_node)
css_book_two_node = nodeData.Node("css in depth", css_node)
js_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("you don't know js", js_node)
js_book_two_node = nodeData.Node("eloquent javascript", js_node)
php_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("modern php", php_node)
python_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("dive into python", python_node)
python_book_two_node = nodeData.Node("python for everybody", python_node)
python_book_three_node = nodeData.Node("Think Python", python_node)
mongodb_book_one_node = nodeData.Node("mongodb in action", mongodb_node)
mongodb_two_node = nodeData.Node("scaling mongodb", mongodb_node)
```

### Output

From node tree abstraction to python dictionary

> {"books":{
>          "web":{
>            "front-end":{
>              "html":["the missing manual", "core html5 canvas"],
>              "css":["css pocket reference", "css in depth"],
>              "js":["you don't know js", "eloquent javascript"]
>            },
>            "back-end":{
>              "php":["modern php"],
>              "python":["dive into python", "python for everybody", 
>              "Think Python"]
>            }
>          },
>          "database":{
>            "sql":{
>              "mysql":[],
>              "postgresql":[]
>            },
>            "nosql":{
>              "mongodb":["mongodb in action", "scaling mongodb"],
>              "cassandra":[]
>      }}}}

### Updated Code

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self._name = name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent

        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)

    def addChild(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

class categoryNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(categoryNode, self).__init__(name, parent)

class subCategoryNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(subCategoryNode, self).__init__(name, parent)

class languageNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(languageNode, self).__init__(name, parent)

class BookNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super(BookNode, self).__init__(name, parent)


rootNode   = Node("books")
web_node = categoryNode("web", rootNode)
database_node = categoryNode("database", rootNode)
front_end_node = subCategoryNode("front-end", web_node)
back_end_node = subCategoryNode("back-end", web_node)
sql_node = subCategoryNode("sql", database_node)
nosql_node = subCategoryNode("nosql", database_node)
html_node = languageNode("html", front_end_node)
css_node = languageNode("css", front_end_node)
js_node = languageNode("js", front_end_node)
php_node = languageNode("php", back_end_node)
python_node = languageNode("python", back_end_node)
mysql_node = languageNode("mysql", sql_node)
postgresql_node = languageNode("postgresql", sql_node)
mongodb_node = languageNode("mongodb", nosql_node)
cassandra_node = languageNode("cassandra", nosql_node)
html_book_one_node = BookNode("the missing manual", html_node)
html_book_two_node = BookNode("core html5 canvas", html_node)
css_book_one_node = BookNode("css pocket reference", css_node)
css_book_two_node = BookNode("css in depth", css_node)
js_book_one_node = BookNode("you don't know js", js_node)
js_book_two_node = BookNode("eloquent javascript", js_node)
php_book_one_node = BookNode("modern php", php_node)
python_book_one_node = BookNode("dive into python", python_node)
python_book_two_node = BookNode("python for everybody", python_node)
python_book_three_node = BookNode("Think Python", python_node)
mongodb_book_one_node = BookNode("mongodb in action", mongodb_node)
mongodb_two_node = BookNode("scaling mongodb", mongodb_node)
```

Comment: I note that you've edited the question to introduce a new class hierarchy for the data structure. I don't think this was necessary, since the question had already been answered; it's not fair on the answerers to expect us to edit our answers to keep up with changes to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bigger problem, because you're using the same class to represent both book categories and actual books. Given this, it is impossible to programmatically determine that `mysql_node` and `postgresql_node` are empty categories rather than books.

To make this work how you want, you will need to redesign the data structure. I suggest having a list `_children` for subcategories and another list `_books` for book titles (as strings). Note that this data structure is still a little ambiguous because a node with no subcategories and no books could be rendered as an empty list (i.e. a terminal category with no books) or an empty dictionary (i.e. a non-terminal category with no subcategories); I infer from the question that an empty list is the desired result.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self._name = name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent
        self._books = []

        if parent is not None:
            parent.addChild(self)

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def setName(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def addChild(self, child):
        if self._books:
            raise ValueError('Node cannot have both sub-categories and books')
        self._children.append(child)

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def addBook(self, book):
        if self._children:
            raise ValueError('Node cannot have both sub-categories and books')
        self._books.append(book)

    def book(self, row):
        return self._books[row]

    def bookCount(self):
        return len(self._books)

rootNode = Node("books")
web_node = Node("web", rootNode)
database_node = Node("database", rootNode)
front_end_node = Node("front-end", web_node)
back_end_node = Node("back-end", web_node)
sql_node = Node("sql", database_node)
nosql_node = Node("nosql", database_node)
html_node = Node("html", front_end_node)
css_node = Node("css", front_end_node)
js_node = Node("js", front_end_node)
php_node = Node("php", back_end_node)
python_node = Node("python", back_end_node)
mysql_node = Node("mysql", sql_node)
postgresql_node = Node("postgresql", sql_node)
mongodb_node = Node("mongodb", nosql_node)
cassandra_node = Node("cassandra", nosql_node)

html_node.addBook("the missing manual")
html_node.addBook("core html5 canvas")
css_node.addBook("css pocket reference")
css_node.addBook("css in depth")
js_node.addBook("you don't know js")
js_node.addBook("eloquent javascript")
php_node.addBook("modern php")
python_node.addBook("dive into python")
python_node.addBook("python for everybody")
python_node.addBook("Think Python")
mongodb_node.addBook("mongodb in action")
mongodb_node.addBook("scaling mongodb")

def node_to_dict(node):
    def helper(n):
        if n.childCount() > 0:
            return { c.name(): helper(c) for c in n._children }
        else:
            return list(n._books)
    return { node.name(): helper(node) }
```

The result of `node_to_dict(rootNode)` does `==` your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Simple recursive function:

```
def to_dict(node):
  if isinstance(node, nodeData.Node):
     return {node._name:to_dict(node._children)}
  if all(isinstance(i, nodeData.Node) for i in node):
     return (lambda x:x if all(x.values()) else list(x))({i._name:to_dict(i._children) for i in node})
  return node

print(to_dict(rootNode))
```

Output:

```
{'books': {'web': {'front-end': {'html': ['the missing manual', 'core html5 canvas'], 'css': ['css pocket reference', 'css in depth'], 'js': ["you don't know js", 'eloquent javascript']}, 'back-end': {'php': ['modern php'], 'python': ['dive into python', 'python for everybody', 'Think Python']}}, 'database': {'sql': ['mysql', 'postgresql'], 'nosql': ['mongodb', 'cassandra']}}}
```

Comment: The output has a problem: `'sql': ['mysql', 'postgresql']`. The desired output should have `'sql': {'mysql': [], 'postgresql': []}`.

Comment: @kaya3 `'sql': {'mysql': [], 'postgresql': []}` is logically inconsistent with the majority of child value outputs such as `["the missing manual", "core html5 canvas"]`.

Comment: Indeed, it is; there is no way to programmatically tell the difference between books and empty categories using the original data structure. But nonetheless this solution gives a different output than the one required in the question, which is an important caveat.

Comment: Hello, i have made some changes in code. Please see updated code in question.